# "Binomial Expansion" with a Complex Exponent

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I want to expand,
$$
(X + Y)^s
$$
for $ X,Y \geq 0 $ and $ s \in \mathbb{C} $.

Into something of the form,
$$
\sum_i X^{p_i} Y^{q_i}
$$
for $ p_i, q_i \in \mathbb{C} $.

I am doing this to expand the Mellin transform of a sum of random variables. The Mellin transform is defined as,
$$
\{\mathcal{M}f_X\}(s) = \mathbb{E}_{f_X}[X^{s-1}] = \int_0^{+\infty} x^{s-1} f_X(x) dx
$$

I have tried doing,
$$
(X+Y)^s = e^{s \log (X+Y)}
$$
and Taylor expanding the exponential and then the log inside the exponential expansion, but $ X + Y $ can go to zero leaving the $ \log X + Y \rightarrow -\infty $.

My complex analysis is rusty and I am a physicist, so this may be very easy and I am just unaware. Please cite theorems used.

Comment: what's your definition of $X^s$ ?

Comment: Good point. Care to make a recommendation? I am trying to expand the Mellin transform. I edited the post. Doing the log thing I tried may work because the log will blow up on a zero measure point. But I would like rigor to my physicist intuition in this case!